# Usando o Symfony como iniciar o banco de dados automaticamente ao implantar o projeto

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, symfony

Existe algum lugar no Symfony reservado para eu disponibilizar scripts ou executar uma classe que popule o banco de dados com as informações iniciais que eu preciso?

O ideal seria durante a primeira execução e a cada atualização. Se existe como eu uso?

Comment: O que você procura se chama Migrations, o Symfony utiliza o Doctrine como Object Relational Mapper, caso você esteja utilizando o Doctrine é possível utilizar o Bundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um recurso no Doctrine chamado Doctrine Migrations. Você pode versionar seu banco de dados e inclusive adicionar uma carga inicial ao executar o comando "migrate".
Existe um Bundle do Symfony2 para isso: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Espero ter ajudado.